# php loop interactions taking too long to complete

Tags: php

The following loop is taking 13 seconds to run on a Windows i7 @ 3.4Ghz 16GB.
The script is running from the command line - php loop.php

```
$start = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i <= 150000; $i++) {
    $running_time = date('i:s', microtime(true) - $start);
    echo "$i - $running_time\n";
}
```

If I take out the 'echo', it takes less than a second, why?

Comment: output is expensive, especially when printing to a console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with lack of buffering of your output.  If you run this in a Windows console, you'll find that the console is your bottleneck.

Hold the scroll bar and watch your program hang until you release it again, to prove this.